# Como puedo usar un dato que viene dado desde un archivo json?

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

complementando mi pregunta este es mi archivo json:

```
{
  "player": [
    {
      "Coordenada Y":7.214575709504705,
      "Coordenada X":28.484783109249697,
      "ID":"116",
      "Velocidad":1
    }
  ]
}
```

Desde el cual quiero obtener la "Velocidad" para poder usarla en un personaje y que se mueva con esa velocidad especificada en el archivo json, para leer este archivo tengo el siguiente código.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Reader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset jsonData;
    public PlayerList players = new PlayerList();

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Player
    {
        public float CoordenadaY;
        public float CoordenadaX;
        public string ID;
        public float Velocidad;
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class PlayerList
    {
        public Player[] player;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        players = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerList>(jsonData.text);
    }
}
```

Cualquier tip o ayuda estaré profundamente agradecido.

Actualización:

```
gameManager GameManager;
private Animator animator;

void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    players = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerList>(jsonData.text);
    transform.Translate(GameManager.moveVector * 
    players.player.Velocidad * Time.deltaTime);
    animator.SetFloat("Speed", players.player.Velocidad);

}
```

Comment: si ya leiste el archivo con `players` no lo obtienes con: `players.player.Velocidad` ???

Comment: eso debes agregarlo al post usa el boton de editar y agregalo.

Comment: En qué parte guardas el objeto en un archivo json ?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ahí lo arregle, gracias por el consejo

Comment: @Mateo No lo estoy guardando en un archivo json, quiero sacar el dato de la velocidad desde el archivo json

Comment: Estas utlizando **variables** en las clases PlayerList y Player, paraque se puedan "serializar" deben ser **Propiedades** (get/set). Desconozco el metodo *JsonUtility.FromJson" (debe ser algo de UnityEngine)

Comment: Estoy mirando la documentacion de [UniteEngine > JsonUtility.FromJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) donde el ejemplo esta con variables publicas, pero no dice nada de los objetos "relacionados". Para ver un ejemplo y encontre que [*No soporta array"](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1123326/jsonutility-array-not-supported.html), pero hay una forma de extender par que puendas (y desconozco si se puede utilizar otro componente para deserializar)

Answer (score 0):

La variable `public Player[] player` es un arreglo. Por lo tanto no puedes acceder directamente al campo `Velocidad`. Antes necesitas acceder a un elemento del arreglo.

Por ejemplo, el primero:

```
players.player[0].Velocidad;
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, veré que puedo hacer con este detalle que había omitido.

Answer (score 0):

Estas utlizando **variables** en las clases PlayerList y Player, para que se puedan "serializar" deben ser **Propiedades** (get/set).
Por ejemplo (utlizando System.Text.Json)

- [Deserializar NET6 utilizando System.Text.Json > https://dotnetfiddle.net/D9mMND](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D9mMND)

Quedaria algo asi

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Player
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Coordenada Y")]
    public float CoordenadaY {get; set;}
    
    [JsonPropertyName("Coordenada X")]
    public float CoordenadaX {get; set;}
    
    [JsonPropertyName("ID")]
    public string ID {get; set;}
    
    [JsonPropertyName("Velocidad")]
    public float Velocidad {get; set;}
}

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerList
{
    [JsonPropertyName("player")]
    public Player[] Player {get; set;}
}
```

Y puedes deserializar,

```
private const string JSON_DATA = "{" +
                                    "  \"player\": [" +
                                    "    {" +
                                    "      \"Coordenada Y\":7.214575709504705," +
                                    "      \"Coordenada X\":28.484783109249697," +
                                    "      \"ID\":\"116\"," +
                                    "      \"Velocidad\":1" +
                                    "    }" +
                                    "  ]" +
                                    "}";


    var players1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PlayerList>(JSON_DATA);
    Console.WriteLine(players1.Player.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine($"players1.Player[0].Velocidad = {players1.Player[0].Velocidad}");
```

Si bien el ejemplo esta con System.Text.Json, puede servir de ayuda en tu caso.

Mirando la documentacion de [UniteEngine > JsonUtility.FromJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) donde el ejemplo esta con variables publicas, pero no dice nada de los objetos "relacionados". Para ver un ejemplo y encontre que [*No soporta array"](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1123326/jsonutility-array-not-supported.html), pero hay una forma de extender para que puedas realizar la parte de PlayersList que tiene la propiedad como array o list de Player (y desconozco si se puede utilizar otro componente para deserializar)

Esspero que sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo, me nace otra duda, con esta deserialización, podré ocupar la velocidad presentada en el json como una parámetro para poder mover mi personaje con el dato puesto en el archivo?